# Can i add link in my website and open an instagram story?

Tags: ios, hyperlink, instagram

In my webpage, I have created a link to redirect my visitors to my Instagram story.

On android, all work very well but on ios doesn't work

This is my URL Android:
    intent://instagram.com/stories/myInstagramUsername/#Intent;package=com.instagram.android;scheme=https;end

What's the correct URL for open Instagram App in Ios?
I won't try:

`Instagram://stories?username=myInstagramUsername`

but not work

Thanks For Your Help

Answer (score 0):

if let url = URL(string: "your story link here") {

```
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
}
```

}

Comment: Tnx for your help. I'm in html webpage how can i use this code?